# Are the physical memory addresses of an array also stored in order like the virtual ones?

Tags: memory, operating-system

I mean when we have in C++ a table:
`int tab[3] = {1,2,3};` we know that if `tab` address is X then address of `tab[1]` is X + 1. I've been reading a bit about virtual and physical addresses, so I guess these addresses are virtual. So if in physical memory `tab` is Y address then `tab[1]` is Y+1 or doesn't have to?

Answer (score 3):

First; everything that's contiguous within a page will be contiguous for both virtual memory and physical memory.

If the array happens to be split across a page boundary (e.g. first half in one page, second half in another page), or if the array is too big to fit in 2 (or 3) pages, then it will still be contiguous in virtual memory, but may not be contiguous in physical memory.

For most things, "non-contiguous in physical memory" doesn't matter.

However; for (direct mapped and associative) caches there's potential efficiency loss. To understand this imagine if there's a 64 KiB cache and you have a 64 KiB array, but the physical addresses happen to use the same entries in the cache - you can end up with the array fighting for the same small amount of cache (and being unable to use most of the cache).

To prevent this problem good operating systems use something called "page colouring" or "cache colouring"; which mostly means that physical pages are allocated so that the pages (the bits of the address that matter for determining where in the cache the data would end up) seem contiguous (even if the physical pages are not actually contiguous). You can read more about this here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coloring

Answer (score 2):

It does not have to be. The operating system is free to use any mapping of virtual memory to physical memory that the hardware can support. Some of the virtual memory addresses may not even map to physical memory if, for example, the contents of parts of the table have been swapped to disk due to a shortage of physical memory.